# PHP Usort by modified filedate not working?

Tags: php

This approach does not work, i have no idea why, from various examples i've seen this should be the way to make usort sort files by modified date but it doesn't appear to work:

```
$myDirectory = opendir($currdir) or die();

while (false !== ($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))) {
    $dirArray[] = array('filename' => $entryName, 'isdir' => is_dir($currdir.'/'.$entryName));
}

closedir($myDirectory);

$indexCount = count($dirArray);

usort($dirArray, function($a,$b){
  return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);
});
```

Comment: When you say something doesn't work or appear to work, be specific. What happens, are there any errors/warnings, etc.

Comment: sorry, i'm getting a warning saying: filemtime() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in d:/test/index.php on line 106. which is my usort part, the files are being displayed but it doesn't look like they are in the order i wanted them to be

Comment: Ok, so there's a warning. That means this code could all work correctly, but the warning is causing something to break. So take a look at the message " filemtime() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path" and then ask yourself: is parameter 1 a valid path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your warning said, you have to pass a path, not an array. This is what you have to do :

```
usort($dirArray, function($a,$b){
    return filemtime($a['filename']) - filemtime($b['filename']);
});
```

Result may look strange because your array includes the directories. But files are sorted by date.

Comment: @KayakinKoder already wrote about it in his comment. karnehe had to answer what corrections he had made to his code.